# XMLBeans: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\xmlbeans\bin\jar":

Tags: java, apache, xmlbeans

I'm trying to run XMLBeans:

```
scomp -compiler "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_37\bin\javac.exe" -cp "C:\Components\*";"C:\Components\jsr173_api.jar";"C:\xmlbeans\lib\xbean.jar";"C:\xmlbeans\lib\xbean_xpath.jar";"C:\xmlbeans\lib\jaxen-1.1-beta-2.jar;" -out S2002PDPIn.jar S2002PDPIn.xsd
```

It gets an error below:

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\xmlbeans\bin\jar": 
CreateProcess error=2, 
The system cannot find the file specified
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.tool.CodeGenUtil.externalJar(CodeGenUtil.java:304)
        at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.tool.SchemaCompiler.compile(SchemaCompiler.java:841)
        at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.tool.SchemaCompiler.main(SchemaCompiler.java:272)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(Unknown Source)
        ... 6 more
BUILD FAILED
```

At first I thought the "C:\xmlbeans\bin\jar" it was looking for was a directory so I just created a folder "jar", but when I run it again the "jar" was referred as a file where I get error:

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\xmlbeans\bin\jar": 
CreateProcess error=5, Access is denied
```

Please kindly help me how to fix this so that it don't look for "jar" file.
I looked "scomp.cmd" but there is no line that will do this.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You are simply calling more applications, than you expect:

```
scomp -compiler "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_37\bin\javac.exe" -cp  "C:\Components\*";

"C:\Components\jsr173_api.jar";

"C:\xmlbeans\lib\xbean.jar";

"C:\xmlbeans\lib\xbean_xpath.jar";

"C:\xmlbeans\lib\jaxen-1.1-beta-2.jar;" -out S2002PDPIn.jar S2002PDPIn.xsd
```

This happens because of `";"`, you would have to enclose the complete classpath with one `"` and seperate the values by `;`.